# How to test component import CSS files with Jest and React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have Banner Component and I want to test it should render with CSS. Below is my code:

```
// Banner.tsx

import "./Banner.css";

export default function Banner() {
  return <div data-testid="banner" className="banner" />;
}

// Banner.css
.banner {
    margin-top: var(--banner-mt);
    height: 30vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
            to right,
            rgba(54, 214, 62, 0.794),
            rgba(53, 201, 157, 0.794),
            rgba(32, 155, 212, 0.794)
        ),
        url("../../assets/images/mountain.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    color: "red";
}
```

I want to test Banner Component has render with backgroundImage. I've tried to `console.log(bannerElement.styles)` and I don't see attribute background-image.

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Banner from "../Banner";

describe("Checking Banner Component", () => {
  test("Banner Element should contain background image", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Banner />);
    const bannerElement = getByTestId("banner");
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(bannerElement);
    expect(bannerElement).toHaveStyle("background-image: ../../assets/images/mountain.jpg");
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64639246/6463558 answer your question?